# Setting values in MYSQL with text link?

Tags: php, mysql, message

I'm trying to set up a messaging system. So far i have the resulted diagram. Users can send and receive messages.

I'm trying to let users delete the messages by clicking on the delete text which runs down the far right column.

The delete text runs from an echo shown in the script below.

```
<?php   
if ($inbox['deleted'] == 0)  {

echo "Delete"; 

}

?>
```

The page is setup like so using tables:

```
My Messages
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Date Received    From      Read/Unread    Delete

10/09/2012       James      Read          Delete
```

Is there a way to make the delete text clickable and have a function so that when a user clicks on it this sets a value from '0' to '1' within my 'deleted' table in my 'ptb_messages' mysql database. Causing the message to be hidden from the users inbox.

Im really dumb when it comes to php, ajax and query so please try and explain it to me as easy as possible if you can help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a plain text echo an anchor link...

```
echo '<a href="mylink">Delete</a>';
```

Then, in that destination, page simply evaluate, whether the user is authorized to do that and if yes, delete the record (and probably redirect back or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

use it like this

```
echo "<a href='?del_id=your_id' onClick='your_function'>Delete</a>";
```

and at start of page write this

```
if(isset($_GET['del_id']))
{
    // query for delete.
}
// rest of your code
```

Comment: thanks for this. the thing i'm unclear of is how to set my delete function. would that be something like: function deleted_message() {
   global $connection;
   global $_SESSION;
   global $message_id;
   $query = "destroy *

Answer (score 0):

Try just making the delete button a submit button with an onclick attribute set to a javascript function setting a hidden input field from 0 to 1. 
Here's an example javascript function:

```
function changeVal{
document.getElementById('hiddenDeleteInput').value=1;
}
```

and here's the html:

```
<form action="deletepage.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" onclick="changeVal();" value="Delete"/>
<input type="hidden" value="0" name='hiddenDeleteInput' id="hiddenDeleteInput"/>
</form>
```

or, if you want to, you could just have an anchor tag leading to a delete page that automatically knows you want to delete it without a delete value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

- you have a connection to a mysql database
- a result object of the data you want to output
- a result row is saved in `$inbox`
- an ID in each result row

this would work:

```
<?php
if (isset($GET['delete'])) {
    markEntryAsDeleted((int) $GET['delete']); // writes to DB
}

// fetch data from DB

if($inbox['deleted'] == 0) {
    echo $row['date'], $row['from'], $row['read'];
    echo '<a href="?delete=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a>";
} else {
    // Either echo nothing or a entry marked as deleted
}
?>
```

I would recommend you get a decent tutorial for php and mysql and read it.
It is well documented how you fetch data from a mysql database and also how to process these data.